# dynamically created elements in jquery sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

My Code is like this :

```
$(function  () {
      $("ol.mauDIDROP").sortable({
    group: '.example'
  });
    $("ol.areaDROP").sortable({
    group:  '.example',
    drop: false,
    drag: false,
  });
   $("ol.areaDROP>li>ol").sortable({
      group:  '.example',
      drop: true,

  });
});
```

Demo & complete code : https://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/15qvta6p/6/

Drag & drop is working

But if :

```
<li>Single Room<ol></ol></li>
      <li>Double Room<ol></ol></li>
      <li>Family Room<ol></ol></li>
```

I move to javascript to use append like this : https://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/kdf7xngk/1/

Drag & drop is not working

Any suggestions on how I can solve this problem?

Thank you

Comment: thanks for posting your application in the jsfiddle, but it may be helpful to pull out the relevantly changed portions of code to include in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your script to:

```
 $(function() {
   $("ol.areaDROP").append("<li>Single Room<ol></ol></li><li>Double Room<ol></ol></li><li>Family Room<ol></ol></li>");
   $("ol.mauDIDROP").sortable({
     group: '.example'
   });
   $("ol.areaDROP").sortable({
     group: '.example',
     drop: false,
     drag: false,
   });
   $("ol.areaDROP>li>ol").sortable({
     group: '.example',
     drop: true,

   });
 });
```